# Start Thread in Backgroundworker and keep thread available

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have backgroundworker in while loop and In this backgroundworker Thread start when is not started yet.
I'm trying to keep thread1 alive and start in again and again when it's not started yet.

I searched a lot of topics about Thread - and i see i have error because my Thread is terminated.

```
public static void DoWork()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("dowork1");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("dowork2");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("dowork3");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("dowork4");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(DoWork);


        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Background worker work");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                if (thread1.IsAlive == false)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        thread1.Start();
                    }
                    catch { };

                }

            }

        }
```

My output when i run above code is :

```
Background worker work
Background worker work
dowork1
Background worker work
dowork2
dowork3
Background worker work
Background worker work
dowork4
Wątek 0x1690 zakończył działanie z kodem 0 (0x0).
„WindowsFormsApp6.exe” (CLR v4.0.30319: WindowsFormsApp6.exe): załadowano „C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_pl_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll”. Moduł został skompilowany bez symboli.
Zgłoszony wyjątek: „System.Threading.ThreadStateException” w mscorlib.dll
Background worker work
Zgłoszony wyjątek: „System.Threading.ThreadStateException” w mscorlib.dll
Background worker work
Zgłoszony wyjątek: „System.Threading.ThreadStateException” w mscorlib.dll
Background worker work
Zgłoszony wyjątek: „System.Threading.ThreadStateException” w mscorlib.dll
Background worker work
Zgłoszony wyjątek: „System.Threading.ThreadStateException” w mscorlib.dll
```

All i want is to keep this repeat. And check when thread1 is not running start it again.
Can someone help me with that? 
Please be patient.
Thanks!
I need to  output like this :

```
Background worker work
Background worker work
dowork1
Background worker work
dowork2
dowork3
Background worker work
Background worker work
dowork4
Background worker work
Background worker work
dowork1
Background worker work
dowork2
dowork3
Background worker work
Background worker work
dowork4
Background worker work
Background worker work
dowork1
Background worker work
dowork2
dowork3
Background worker work
Background worker work
dowork4
and forever...
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What's your use case? Your solution looks very strange so describe your problem.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use `Thread` rather than `Task`?

Comment: no there isn't , can you show as answear how to do that and have the same result? :) @mjwills

Comment: Have you used `Task.Run` before?

Comment: Ye, i tried it with tasks before but i see Thread works better than Task,  don't know how to get the same result using Task.

Comment: @adam - What result are you getting with Threads that you can't get with Tasks?

Comment: @adam - Also, mixing `BackgroundWorker` and threads is probably a bad idea. Choose one, not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From doc:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.start?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Thread_Start_System_Object_)

> Once the thread terminates, it cannot be restarted with another call to Start.

You have to add this again before calling Start:

```
thread1 = new Thread(DoWork);
```

Anyway the proper way to keep alive a thread waiting for background work is to keep it *really* alive, not to restart it. Or, better, use the [ThreadPool](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool?view=netframework-4.8).